# NSFetchedResultsController refresh for fetching new data

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Please direct me to the right way.

I implemented this code to fetch my objects:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSPredicate *predicate = nil;

    if (self.selectedCategory)
    {
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY category_ids.category_id == %@", self.selectedCategory];
    }

    _fetchedResultsController = [EyeArtist fetchAllGroupedBy:nil withPredicate:predicate sortedBy:@"artist_id" ascending:NO delegate:self];

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

So when app run the at first time fetch works without predicate, so at second time I need new fetch with predicate.

I tap on the button and set string self.selectedCategory, but I don't know how to refetch data from - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController;

So I suppose it has to be like execute new request for fetchedResultsController instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After changing the search criteria, you have to set the instance variable `self.fetchedResultsController` to `nil`,
so that the next call to the "lazy getter" function creates a new FRC with the 
changed predicate. Something like this:

```
self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: If a getter was used ... if you just initialised the FRC under self.fetchedResultsController there's no FRC left after the `_frc = nil;`

Comment: @Evils: After setting `_fetchedResultsController = nil;`, the next call to `self.fetchedResultsController` will recreate the FRC in the getter method (now using the changed search criteria).

Comment: That's what I meant when saying if a getter was used. You mentioned the lazy getter but most people will probably not understand that you assumed there's a proper getter in place. Anyway, my comment wasn't necessarily making that clear, my fault!

Answer (score 0):

This is the pattern I use for where a fetch controller needs a property:

```
- (void)setSelectedCategory:(id)selectedCategory{
    if(selectedCategory == _selectedCategory){
         return _selectedCategory
    }
    _selectedCategory = selectedCategory;
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    if(self.isViewLoaded){
        [self.tableView reloadData]; // but better to put this in an update views method that you can also call from viewDidLoad.
    }
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    id selectedCategory = self.selectedCategory;
    // Only need this if a category is required.
    if(!selectedCategory){
        return nil;
    }
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY category_ids.category_id == %@", selectedCategory];
    _fetchedResultsController = [EyeArtist fetchAllGroupedBy:nil withPredicate:predicate sortedBy:@"artist_id" ascending:NO delegate:self];
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```